# Number of solutions $(x_1)(x_2)(x_3)(x_4) = 2016$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Having some trouble wrapping my head around this one:

> find the number of solutions to the equation $(x_1)(x_2)(x_3)(x_4) = 2016$, where $(x_i)$s are integers that are not necessarily positive.

Here's what I've been thinking so far:

Let's bring $2016$ down to its prime factorized form, such that we have $2016 = 2^5\times3^2\times7^1$.

Because the solution may include negative integers, note that a pair or 4 integers will form positive numbers, therefore we have $C(4,2)$ OR $C(4,4)$ ways of doing this.

Let's also note that the solution may include 1s in $3, 2, 1$, or $0$ positions for $(x_i)$, such that we have $C(4,3), C(4,2), C(4,1)$, or $C(4,0)$.

Now I'm thinking that we should look at each particular element of the prime factorization, such that we have elements $2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7$ that are not entirely distinct. We should now think of the number of ways we can fill in $8$ elements into each of these $1, 2, 3$, or $4$ positions depending on the number of 1s we have.

And this is where I am having a little bit of trouble thinking through the solution. I'm thinking I could check the number of distinct integers that I could form with $2^5\times3^2\times7^1$ and then go from there? But I'm having trouble thinking through this methodology as well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I will assume that you want the number of *ordered* quadruples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_1x_2x_3x_4=2016$.

First let us find the number of ordered quadruples of *positive* integers.

We want to distribute the five $2$'s between $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

By [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) there are $\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}$ ways to do this.

For each such choice we need to distribute the two $3$'s, and then the one $7$. I will assume you know now how to complete this part. Call the resulting number $N$.

To take account of negative possibilities, we could have all negative, giving another $N$ choices, or two positive and two negative, giving another $\binom{4}{2}N$ choices.

Comment: So the final answer is $(1 + 1 + \binom{4}{2})N$ choices?

Comment: Yes. I am leaving the rest of the calculation of $N$ to you. If there is a problem, please leave a message.

Comment: Oh, I'm not the OP. Just wanted to make sure I understood :)

Comment: Apologies, I assumed, without checking, that you were.

Comment: Thank you for providing some intuition André. The link to Stars and Bars helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. The Stars and Bars technique will come up again. In our particular case, we don't need Stars and Bars to see that there are just $4$ ways to distribute the $7$. And the $3$'s are pretty simple too. Either somebody gets both ($4$ ways) or two people get one each ($\binom{4}{2}$) for a total of $10$. The $2$'s are more work. But by breaking into cases, it can be done. However, with larger numbers of things to distribute, Stars and Bars becomes indispensable.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is hidden in
2^5*3^2*7
We have to select 4 factor whose multiplication is 2016

So for selecting 4 factor there are
C(8,2)waysways

&you have to also include negative no 
Cases

Comment: This might work better as a comment, as it seems to need some improvements to get the actual answer.  See if learning [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ to post mathematical expressions appeals to you.